# Solve $\int \frac{dz}{(A^2+z^2)\sqrt{2A^2+z^2}}$

Tags: integration, substitution

Let A be a constant and z a variable.

Compute the integral:

$\int \frac{dz}{(A^2+z^2)\sqrt{2A^2+z^2}}$

Note: I've tried the most common trigonometric substitutions (like z = Atan($\theta$)), but had no success.

Comment: Just making a suggestion that using $z=A\tan \theta$ would not make it very easy because here the main cause of trouble is the root in denominator and the substitution does not help to get rid of it. Also another substitution you can use is putting $z=\frac 1x$ and then substitute the term inside root as $y$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $z=\sqrt{2}A\tan \theta$

The integral becomes (I will just skip the trivial steps)
$$\int \frac{\cos\theta d\theta}{A^2(1+\sin^2\theta)}  = \frac{1}{A^2}\int \frac{ d\sin\theta}{1+\sin^2\theta} = \frac{\arctan(\sin\theta)}{A^2}$$

I think this is clear enough and you can figure out the rest.

Answer (score 2):

you Can use the Substitution $$\sqrt{2A^2+z^2}=t+z$$ then you will get $$z=\frac{2A^2-t^2}{2t}$$ and $$dz=-\frac{2 A^2+t^2}{2 t^2}dt$$